# List-initializer and variadic constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list, variadic

From [CPP reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) on list-initialisation:

> Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
> - All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single argument of type std::initializer_list
> - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all)

So a constructor using `initializer_list` is considered first. Failing that, each element of the list is considered as arguments for constructors. However

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A{
    template <typename... Args> A(Args... li) { cout << sizeof...(Args) << endl;}
};

int main(){

    A a = {2,3,4};

}
```

The output is `3` which indicates that `Args...` unpacks as `int, int, int`. Why is it that Args... was not simply made the singular `initializer_list<int>`, which the details on list-initialisation indicated would be the first attempted type of constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[temp.deduct.call]/1** Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it `P`) with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below. If removing references and cv-qualifiers from `P` gives `std::initializer_list<P'>` for some `P'` and the argument is an initializer list (8.5.4), then deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer list, taking `P'` as a function template parameter type and the initializer element as its argument. Otherwise, **an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context (14.8.2.5).**

Emphasis mine. For this reason, template argument deduction for the constructor from an argument of type `initializer_list<int>` fails.

Comment: Just to be clear, an `initializer_list<int>` argument would result in successful template argument deduction in `A(Args...)`. So the first line of my CPP quote (transforming to an `initialiser_list` argument) applies to finding the candidate non-template constructors, while your quote applies to finding the candidate template functions using template argument deduction. If neither the template or non-template functions provide a suitable candidate, each list element is considered as a separate argument.

Comment: There's a note in **[dcl.init.list]/2**: "Passing an initializer list as the argument to the constructor template `template<class T> C(T)` of a class `C` does not create an initializer-list constructor, because an initializer list argument causes the corresponding parameter to be a non-deduced context (14.8.2.1)." That's what led me to **[temp.deduct.call]**. Now, it is true that changing `main` in your program to `std::initializer_list<int> l{2,3,4}; A a = l;` compiles. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ah. **[temp.deduct.call]/1** talks about the case where the argument is an initializer list (that is, a sequence of comma-separated values enclosed in braces), not an instance of `std::initializer_list`. The distinction is important, the two are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide explicitly a constructor with `std::initializer_list`, it would be choose: 
[Demo](https://ideone.com/9ta3BC).

`template <typename... Args> A(Args...)` is not a constructor with first argument `std::initializer_list` (even if first argument may be an `std::initializer_list`).

And in `A a = {2, 3, 4}`, `{2, 3, 4}` has no type. It is not a `std::initializer_list`.